# Adaptive User Interface based on user experience

Tags: interface

I need to modify a web application's interface based on user behavior. For example, new users will see the interface in a simplified way and expert users will see all the features of the application. How can I distinguish between the two types of users? The web application is built on Flask. How should I approach and is there any constructive tutorial that I can follow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Cookies/Local Storage to count and save how many times they have visited, or if they have visited before. This can be done through Flask, see here for how it's done: [link](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-cookies/).

Alternatively, give the user the option to toggle between the views, and use a cookie to save their option.

Comment: If this is the solution you plan to use, please mark this as the answer so others can find the same answer easier. @glitters